# how to construct specific mercurial ignore patterns?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I would like to ignore all files that start with:

```
._
```

How would I write this in the .hgignore file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat .hgignore
syntax: glob
._*
```

Which I have tested thusly (with some "noise" like `..` removed for clarity):

```
$ ls -aRF
.:
a  ._a   .hgignore  sub/

./sub:
a  ._a
$ hg stat
? .hgignore
? a
? sub/a
```